# Letters displayed ridiculously huge (or small) when using 'em' to specify font-size

Tags: css, font-size

I'm experiencing some pretty bizarre behaviour from my CSS font-size rules. I'm probably doing something silly myself [this must be the case ;-) ], but I hope someone can point it out for me.

Currently (for testing purposes) I have only one rule for font-size in the stylesheet, that regulates ALL font-sizes, and this is it:

```
p, div, a, span {
    font-size:3em;
}
```

Now I know 3em is a pretty big font-size (for all I know it should correspond to a width of about 3*16 = 48 pixels on the big screen browsers), but what you see in reality is simply ridiculous. Have a look: http://www.svvreewijkdevaan.nl/nl/

If you think the font size in the menu (which you see on top of the page) is big, scroll down a bit, and you'll find that the letters become so huge that they're not really recognizable as letters anymore.

And in fact, looking in the Firefox inspection tool, I find that '3em' letters are computed to have a font-size of (get this) 34992px, i.e. almost 35 thousand. What does that even mean?

In fact, the real (displayed) font-size (i.e. the width) seems to grow - at the very least - *exponentially* with the specified em number, rather than proportionally. So for example, if I replace 3em by 3.5em, the displayed font-size becomes at least two times as wide (actually more). Conversely, if I reduce the specified font-size to 1em I get the - normal and expected - size of about 16px. But if I make it 0.7em, the width reduces to maybe 2px (absolutely unreadably small).

Why don't the real (displayed) font-sizes grow proportionally with font-size (in terms of 'em') specified in my stylesheet?

Comment: `em` is based on the font-size of the _parent_ element. Now, if you _nest_ elements for which you have set the font-size in `em` into each other – those values get _multiplied_. Either don’t nest element with font-sizes set in `em` that much; set it for less elements (for example _only_ for `div` or `p`, and let the descendants inherit the size); or look into the `rem` unit instead.

Comment: You nailed it! Changing em into rem solved the problem immediately. If you make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. And I will think hard and deep about what you said about the nesting of elements, and the need for a parent font-size (when using em). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`em` is based on the font-size of the *parent* element. Now, if you *nest* elements for which you have set the font-size in `em` into each other – those values get *multiplied*.

- Either don’t nest element with font-sizes set in `em` that much;
- set it for less elements (for example only for `div` or `p`, and let the descendants inherit the size);
- or look into the `rem` unit instead.